# How can we give Project Overheads in Primavera P6?

Tags: overhead, primavera

How can we show project overheads in Primavera P6? I have tried by level of efforts but it is not showng.

Answer (score 0):

Add Expenses to include Overhead. Go to activities, Bottom Layout

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use a special activity type - not a level of effort, but a "WBS Summary".

1. Create a new activity.
2. Make it a WBS Summary type.
3. If you want to assign overhead costs to the entire project, then place it at the very top of your WBS structure (right under the project title).
4. Reschedule the project so that it picks up a calculated duration (the duration of the project)
5. Assign an expense to it on the Expenses tab of the activity.